# React Native Paper - DataTable get row

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-paper

How can I get the selected row in React Native Paper DataTables?

My DataTables row mapping:

```
{sortedItems.slice(from, to).map(item => (
    <DataTable.Row key={item.id}>
        <DataTable.Cell>{item.numero}</DataTable.Cell>
        <DataTable.Cell>{item.data}</DataTable.Cell>
        <DataTable.Cell numeric>{item.cliente}</DataTable.Cell>

        <DataTable.Cell numeric>
            <IconButton
                icon="eye"
                onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Details', {/* HERE, HOW TO GET THE ELEMENT??? */}}
            />
        </DataTable.Cell>
    </DataTable.Row>
))}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just get the item on mapping time:

```
{sortedItems.slice(from, to).map(item => (
    <DataTable.Row key={item.id}>
        <DataTable.Cell>{item.numero}</DataTable.Cell>
        <DataTable.Cell>{item.data}</DataTable.Cell>
        <DataTable.Cell numeric>{item.cliente}</DataTable.Cell>

        <DataTable.Cell numeric>
            <IconButton
                icon="eye"
                onPress={() => console.log(item)} /* <--- EASY */
            />
        </DataTable.Cell>
    </DataTable.Row>
))}
```